# Vertical image spacing in Pandoc generated PDF

Tags: pandoc

I work on generating a large PDF file from a markdown source with Pandoc. The document contains lots of non-floating images without caption.

In these cases, the generated LaTeX code is simply `\includegraphics{path/to/file}`.

The generated PDF shows hardly any whitespace between the image and the paragraphs above and below. I don't see where I can set a vertical margin for images with either Pandoc variables or within the template (e.g. the default template or Eisvogel) because they simply output the Pandoc generated `body` variable.

Is there a way to fix this layout issue (other than inserting line breaks in the markdown)?

Comment: I don't know in terms of `pandoc` markup, but you can use something like `\begin{center} ... \end{center}` if you don't want a `figure`. You can also use the `H` with `figure` and no caption, though this isn't recommended (but it's not worse than other non-floating solutions as far as I know). But, generally, inserting images this way is going to make it hard for TeX to produce decent output because floats are part of the way you get reasonable spacing.

Comment: I imagine you know that pandoc allows to include raw tex within markdown source. So, for example, you could define a command for your images and put its definition in the template.

Comment: @cfr: The problem is that Pandoc builds the document body on its own and includes it in the template, so I don't know how to insert LaTeX commands here. Maybe it would be a solution to convert to LaTeX, insert some commands and only then build the PDF instead of generating the PDF in one step.

Comment: @Iacobus1983 interesting idea but I still need to figure out how to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can automatically add, e.g., a `center` environment to each `\includegraphics` not used inside given environments like `figure`, `table`, `center`, `flushleft` or `flushright`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\NewCommandCopy{\savedincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\expandafter,\@currenvir,}%
  {,figure,table,center,flushleft,flushright,}%
  \ifin@
    \savedincludegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
  \else 
    \begin{center}\savedincludegraphics[{#1}]{#2}\end{center}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-a}
\blindtext[2]

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-b}
  \caption{Test (intended to not be centered)}
\end{figure}

\blindtext Next image also should be left aligned.
\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[scale=.5]{example-image-c}
\end{flushleft}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

I don't know how to tell `pandoc` to add the code

```
\NewCommandCopy{\savedincludegraphics}{\includegraphics}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{%
  \expandafter\in@\expandafter{\expandafter,\@currenvir,}%
  {,figure,table,center,flushleft,flushright,}%
  \ifin@
    \savedincludegraphics[{#1}]{#2}%
  \else 
    \begin{center}\savedincludegraphics[{#1}]{#2}\end{center}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

to the document preamble, but I'm sure, it would be possible.

But note: The redefinition would also be valid for, e.g., using `\includegraphics` in page headers or title pages.

Note: If you want to extend the comma separated list

```
{,figure,table,center,flushleft,flushright,}
```

don't forget the comma at the start and the end!

Note: If you'd use `\includegraphics` inside, e.g., a `tabular` inside a `table`, the `table` environment is not recognized by my re-definition of `\includegraphics`. Only the current inner environment is recognized. But you could, e.g., define a dummy environment:

```
\newenvironment{dontcenter}{}{}
```

and add this to the list. So you could use

```
\begin{dontcenter}\includegraphics{…}\end{dontcenter}
```

for all images inside other environments, which should not be centered.

Comment: You can simply put your code in a FILE and tell pandoc to include it with the command line option `--include-in-header=FILE`